# Tkinter Progressbar: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have a problem where I just do not know how to solve it.

In the controller I run a measurement, in the view I want to implement a progressbar.

To implement the progressbar in the view with the help of a StepValue, so how many steps per second, I need two values from the controller.

In the constructor in the controller I instantiate two StringVars, which are empty at the beginning. In the measurement, with the help of a method from the DeviceLibary, the method is to be called, which returns the times and these are to update the StringVars with the help of the set method.

In the view, the step value should be calculated from this, but apparently the StringVars are not updated.

```
class Controller():  
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.paramset = Paramset() #get parameters
       self.get_test_done_time = tkinter.StringVar()
       self.get_sample_period = tkinter.StringVar()

    def measure_data(self, port):
       try:
           self.dev = Device(port) #Device is a libary
       except Exception:
           messagebox.showerror("Error", "No COM-Port")
           return None
    try:
        self.dev.set_curr_range(self.paramset.curr_range[0].get())
        self.dev.set_sample_rate(float(self.paramset.sampleRate[0].get()))
        t, volt, curr = self.dev.run_test("cyclic", display='pbar',
                                 filename=self.paramset.textdata[0].get())
        self.get_test_done_time.set(self.dev.get_test_done_time())
        self.get_sample_period.set(self.dev.get_sample_period())
        self.dev.stop_test()
        self.dev.close()

def start_test(self, port):
    self.worker = threading.Thread(target=self.measure_data, args=(port,))
    self.worker.start()



Class View:
    def __init__(self):
        self.controller = Controller()
        self.percentLabel = Label(textvariable=self.percent)
        self.progress_frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.progress_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=200)
        self.pb.pack()
        self.progress_frame.grid(row=len(vars(self.controller.paramset)) - 6, column=0)
        self.start_button = ttk.Button(self.buttonframe, text="Start Test", command=lambda: self.start_measurement(self.portVar.get()) or self.start_progress_bar()) #start measurement = start_test in controller


def progress(self):
    if self.variable.get() == "Cyclo":
        if self.controller.worker.is_alive():
            self.stepValue = float(self.controller.get_test_done_time.get())/ float(self.controller.get_sample_period.get())
    while self.pb["value"] < 100:
        self.pb['value'] += self.stepValue
        self.percentLabel['text'] = self.update_progress_label()
        time.sleep(1.2)
        self.update_idletasks()
    if self.pb["value"] == 100:
        self.pb["value"] = 0
        self.percentLabel['text'] = "Current Progress: 0.0%"
        self.pb.stop()
        self.update_idletasks()

def start_progress_bar(self):
    self.progress_worker = threading.Thread(target = lambda:self.progress())
    self.progress_worker.start()
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (<lambda>):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\View.py", line 265, in <lambda>
    self.progress_worker = threading.Thread(target = lambda:self.progress())
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\View.py", line 252, in progress
    self.stepValue = float(self.controller.get_test_done_time.get())/ float(self.controller.get_sample_period.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: i have updated :)

Comment: Looks like either ```self.controller.get_test_done_time.get()``` or ```self.controller.get_sample_period.get()``` returns an 'empty' string.   You should check if either of those return values are ```''```.  If so.  treat the value as '0'

Comment: The is not float "Cyclo". It is string

Comment: I have corrected the spelling error. All variables names are correct, but always an empty string. 

I thought through the thread I can bypass this. Because if the thread is active, the parameters of the measurement are registred and could then access the times I need...

Comment: Use str instead of float.

Comment: but this are numbers and not strings

Comment: In your controller class you have `self.get_test_done_time = tkinter.StringVar()`.  Can you use `tkinter.DoubleVar()` instead?